# Possible Conference Speaking Sponsorships -- 2011

Tags: discussion, conferences

We're evaluating the feasibility of **sponsoring a member of the cooking community to speak at a conference in 2011**.

Speaking is a relatively big "ask", so this needs to be planned many months in advance. Let's get started!

We'd like the community to establish **where** ...

> What relevant cooking conferences are coming up in 2011 that have open speaker slots or calls for papers?

... and then **who**.

> Which members of the community are strongly interested in being sponsored by Stack Exchange, Inc to speak at one of the above conferences in 2011?

To be clear, the speaker is free talk about anything he or she wants so long as it would be roughly on topic for this site -- with a quick acknowledgement of support from Stack Exchange and a mention of the community here.

Comment: I mentioned stack exchange in general during comments at the ASIS&T 2010 annual meeting, as someone was talking about their analysis of Q/A sites.  I don't think it's what you're looking for, but it'd be interesting to analyze if you got better or faster answers with specialized sub-sites vs. generic Q/A sites vs. forum style sites.  Of course, that'd mean research and submitting an abstract, which could take a year or more.

Comment: @Joe, the preparation time isn't that long (and nobody cares about abstracts, the paper submission deadline is what matters). Only the biggest conferences (like ICSE, CHI) have a submission deadline 9 months before the date - but only serious full-time researchers have a chance there. Smaller conferences have shorter prep times, and if somebody is speaking at a workshop housed at a localish conference, the (paper submission) deadline could be as short as 10 weeks. For a full paper, the writing needs ~60 hours after you have the content and the most important references in your head.

Comment: @rumtscho : it depends on the field; ASIS&T used to require the full paper be submitted in Feb/March for a conference in October or November; you could only get away with the abstract-only route if it was a SIG-sponsored session and they had lined up all of the speakers (with the same deadline).  And for papers, you had to have actual results to report to get through peer-review, so you'd have to do something in advance.  Of course, in the last week I put in a session proposal for AGU (December) and two abstracts for AAS/SPD (June), both of which are larger meetings.  (AGU is *huge*)

Comment: @joe awesome, let us know what we can do to assist and sponsor!

Comment: @jeff : no, no ... they're completely unrelated conferences ... just given as an example of time for these things ... they'd be more line with physics, GIS, statistics or data  (and I mean *data* not the rebranded DBA) stack exchange sites.  (AGU == American Geophysical Union; AAS/SPD = American Astronomical Society, Solar Physics Division).  My session for the AGU (assuming it gets approved), is on distributon of science data for re-use, so maybe people from webapps, too ... (not that it'd make sense for to present on the sites, but there might be interest from those communities)

Comment: @joe ah, my bad, I misunderstood.

Answer (score 3):

Hey, this sounds like a really neat idea. The Canadian Restaurant & Food Association show is every March in Toronto--perhaps you could look for 2012?

Answer (score 3):

I saw mention on a blog about the [International Food Bloggers Conference](http://www.foodista.com/ifbc2011/nola/) ... I know we're not a food blog, but it's likely the right type of people that you're trying to attract as experts to answer questions.

Even if there aren't speaker slots for websites such as this, there might be sponsorship opportunities.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a conference, but [Food & Wine runs a bunch of events](http://www.foodandwine.com/promo/events/) each year.  The ones in New York and South Beach are co-sponsored by Food Network ... but I have no idea what any of 'em are like, or what the general attendance is.  I assume it's more for the public than a trade show, based on advertising I've seen on Food Network.